# IE8 not processing Flickr feed

Tags: javascript

I've got a Flickr Image feed running on here:

http://rational-animal.co.uk/lewis -- but when I have a look at it in IE8, it refuses to load the Flickr feed. Any reason why this would be the case?

Thanks!

Comment: Works in IE9 with doc/standards mode set to IE8. You get any errors or anything?

Comment: No, it just doesn't seem to appear. I've been checking in netrenderer, and it seems to appear and disappear at will.